# Why do my filtered emails end up in the Sent label?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I have a number of filter rules in my Gmail account (my goal with my emails is to have every email I receive archived as I receive them, that is, always have an empty inbox) and it works fantastically.

My problem however is that every email that gets affected by a filter rule, for some strange reason, also appears in my `Sent` label. I have not sent these emails to anyone, I have only received them. Why are my Gmail filter rules doing this? And most importantly, how can I make it behave as expected?

This is a screen grab of one of the filter rules I am using, no matter how many times I look at it, I can't see why it would be doing this:

---

[image: Screenshot of filter form]

---

[image: Screenshot of filter options]

This is a Gmail Account through Google Apps for Business. I hope that helps, as I am not 100% on how Googles services relate.

Comment: Could you please give a sample screenshot of what these emails' header look like?